# Production Apply Push Notification Certificate

Tags: iphone

Is it possible for another Apple developer to push notifications to another application if they know the device token?

Answer (score 0):

I would say no. I am pretty sure they look for that in the approval process as well as on the push notification servers.

Comment: I see, so there is no way to have multiple certificates from different apple developer accounts push notifications to one application?